# Как поймать, какие триггеры предупреждают sklearn.GridSearchCV.fit()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, warning, scikit-learn

В функции [rasa_nlu](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu/blob/master/rasa_nlu/classifiers/sklearn_intent_classifier.py#L110) они вызывают [`GridSearchCV.fit()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) с помощью `clf.fit()`. Он вызывает некоторые предупреждения, и я хотел бы поймать и изменить, чтобы узнать, что их вызывает:

```
Fitting 2 folds for each of 6 candidates, totalling 12 fits
/home/mike/Programming/Rasa/myflaskapp/rasaenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py:1135: UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
/home/mike/Programming/Rasa/myflaskapp/rasaenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py:1135: UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
/home/mike/Programming/Rasa/myflaskapp/rasaenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py:1135: UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
/home/mike/Programming/Rasa/myflaskapp/rasaenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py:1135: UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
/home/mike/Programming/Rasa/myflaskapp/rasaenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py:1135: UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
/home/mike/Programming/Rasa/myflaskapp/rasaenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py:1135: UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done  12 out of  12 | elapsed:    0.1s finished
```

Вот как построено «GridSearchCV»:

```
cv_splits = self._num_cv_splits(y) #когда я распечатал его, он дал мне «2», мне ожидалось, что что-то более связанное с ярлыками

GridSearchCV(SVC(C=1,
                probability=True,
                class_weight='balanced'),
            param_grid=tuned_parameters,
            n_jobs=num_threads,
            cv=cv_splits,
            scoring='f1_weighted',
            verbose=1)
```

Где `y` - это `labels`, которые были преобразованы в числа

```
y: [1 0 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 3 3]

labels: ['greet', 'goodbye', 'inform', 'greet', 'greet', 'greet', 'greet', 'greet', 'greet', 'goodbye', 'goodbye', 'goodbye', 'goodbye', 'goodbye', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'laughing', 'laughing']
```

В идеале я хотел бы выяснить, какие из них вызвали предупреждения.

#### Обновление

На данный момент я просто попытался получить происхождение, я до сих пор не нашел способа захватить предупреждение:

```
        y = self.transform_labels_str2num(labels)
        X = np.stack([example.get("text_features")
                      for example in training_data.intent_examples])

        self.clf = self._create_classifier(num_threads, y)
        try:
            fit_result = self.clf.fit(X, y)
            y_pred = self.clf.predict(X)
            print("set(y)-set(y_pred):\n",set(y)-set(y_pred))
```

Но он просто дает мне пустой набор `set()`

Также необходимо использовать `.predict(X)`? Отличается ли он от результатов `clf.fit()`?

Answer (score 1):

Это предупреждение говорит о том, что как минимум для одного предсказываемого класса не было предсказано ни одного значения из данного класса.

Например в вашем случае в векторе предсказаний отсутствуют элементы одного или нескольких классов.

В таких случаях невозможно нормально посчитать `F1 Score` (выбранная вами метрика), поэтому в качестве значения F1 Score для такого класса берется значение `0.0`.

Чтобы понять какие классы отсутствуют в предсказаниях:

```
set(y_test) - set(y_predicted)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за этот ответ! Как создать `y_predicted`?

Comment: @Marine1, y_predicted = clf.predict(X_test)

Comment: Я думаю, что это то, что я сделал, но когда я устанавливаю `set(y_test) - set set(y_pred)`, он пуст. Но у меня есть `Warnings`. Я ошибаюсь в X_test? Я обновил код.